# String heap not inserting properly

Tags: java, data-structures

I've been working on my assignment which is to create a heap of strings, and do various functions on it. I'm now testing my code to see if it's inserting properly, and it's not. I'm testing the words: `Golf, Bravo, Hotel, Alpha, Delta, Echo, Charlie, Foxtrot` which would insert them alphabetically however when I print my heap I end up with:

```
                                Alpha
             Bravo                              Charlie
   Foxtrot              Delta              Hotel              Echo
Golf
```

---

Here is the code that I have written:

```
public boolean insert(String key) {
    if(currentSize == maxSize) {
        return false;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(key);
    heapArray[currentSize] = newNode;
    trickleUp(currentSize++);
    return true;
}

public void trickleUp(int index) {
    int parent = (index - 1) / 2;
    Node bottom = heapArray[index];

    while(index > 0 && heapArray[parent].getKey().compareTo(bottom.getKey()) > 0) {
        heapArray[index] = heapArray[parent];
        index = parent;
        parent = (parent - 1) / 2;
    }
    heapArray[index] = bottom;
}
```

EDIT: After doing a quick search and finding another source code for a Heap, and testing it I was given the same output. Is there a reason why this is not being added alphabetically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you show in your printout is correct for a min heap, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

From the introductory paragraph (emphasis added):

> Either the keys of parent nodes are always greater than or equal to those of the children and the highest key is in the root node (this kind of heap is called max heap) or **the keys of parent nodes are less than or equal to those of the children and the lowest key is in the root node (min heap).**

From the second paragraph (emphasis added):

> there is no implied ordering between siblings or cousins and **no implied sequence for an in-order traversal (as there would be in, e.g., a binary search tree)**. The heap relation mentioned above applies only between nodes and their immediate parents.

Your heap appears correctly ordered, in that each node only has children that are greater than it, alphabetically.